# Swipe delete in Recycler View using threads

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement swipe delete functionality with icons view in my recycler view. somehow I have done it, my adapter is updating list in every 3 seconds and my swipe menu gets invisible and lists get its original view when update comes.I don't want to stop thread while swipe. Please help if you can guysssssssss..

below is my adapter code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.catalyst.maksl.Beans.ChangeStatus;
import com.catalyst.maksl.Beans.MarketFeedBean;
import com.catalyst.maksl.Beans.MarketWatchGraphBean;
import com.catalyst.maksl.Beans.ScripBean;
import com.catalyst.maksl.Components.AutoResizeTextView;
import com.catalyst.maksl.R;
import com.catalyst.maksl.SymbolDetails.SymbolDetailsActivity;
import com.catalyst.maksl.Utills.AppConfig;
import com.catalyst.maksl.Utills.Logs;
import com.catalyst.maksl.Utills.Utilities;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IFillFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.dataprovider.LineDataProvider;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MarketWatchSymbolAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MarketWatchSymbolAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    public Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    private LineDataSet set1;
    public static Drawable drawablePositive = ContextCompat.getDrawable(Logs.globalContext, R.drawable.graph_green_bg);
    public static Drawable drawable_negative = ContextCompat.getDrawable(Logs.globalContext, R.drawable.graph_bg);
    ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    private List<MarketWatchGraphBean> marketWatchGraphBeans = new ArrayList<>();


    public MarketWatchSymbolAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.market_watch_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(listItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        mViewHolder =  holder;
        MarketFeedBean marketFeedBean = Logs.marketFeedBeanMap.get(rows.get(position));
        ScripBean scripBean = Logs.allScripBean.get(rows.get(position));

        marketWatchGraphBeans =  Logs.marketWatchGraphBeansMap.get(rows.get(position));

            updateGraph();
            customiseChart(holder);


        try {
            if (marketFeedBean != null) {

            Double changePercentage = marketFeedBean.getChange() / (marketFeedBean.getLastTradePrice() - marketFeedBean.getChange()) * 100;

            holder.indexName.setText(marketFeedBean.getMarket());
            holder.scripName.setText(marketFeedBean.getScrip());
            holder.SymbolName.setText(marketFeedBean.getScripName());
            holder.indexValue.setText(Logs.priceFormat.format(marketFeedBean.getLastTradePrice()).replace("-", ""));
            if(scripBean != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    holder.sector.setText(scripBean.getSectorName());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Utilities.handleException(e);
                }
            }

            holder.nameIcon.setText(marketFeedBean.getScrip().substring(0, 1));


            if (marketFeedBean.getChange() != 0.0) {
                String c;
                if (Logs.priceFormat.format(changePercentage).contains("-")) {

                    holder.indexValue.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg_negativecell));

                        set1.setColor(Color.RED);
                        set1.setFillDrawable(drawable_negative);
                    c = Logs.priceFormat.format(marketFeedBean.getChange()) + " " + "(" + Logs.priceFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(changePercentage))) + "%)";


                }

                else {

                    holder.indexValue.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.bg_positivecell));

                        set1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        set1.setFillDrawable(drawablePositive);
                    c ="+" + Logs.priceFormat.format(marketFeedBean.getChange())+ " " + "(" + "+"+ Logs.priceFormat.format(changePercentage).replace("-", "") + "%)";



                }

                holder.indexChange.setText(c);



            }

            else {
                holder.indexChange.setText(R.string.zero_percent);
                holder.indexValue.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg_no_change_mw));


            }

            //blinking

            if (marketFeedBean.isLastTradePriceGain.equals(ChangeStatus.HIGH)) {
                holder.indexValue.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg_low));
                holder.indexValue.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.black));
                holder.indexValue.setText(Logs.priceFormat.format(marketFeedBean.getLastTradePrice()).replace("-", ""));
            } else if (marketFeedBean.isLastTradePriceGain.equals(ChangeStatus.LOW)) {
                holder.indexValue.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.black));
                holder.indexValue.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg_low));
                holder.indexValue.setText(Logs.priceFormat.format(marketFeedBean.getLastTradePrice()).replace("-", ""));
            } else {
                holder.indexValue.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white));
                holder.indexValue.setText(Logs.priceFormat.format(marketFeedBean.getLastTradePrice()).replace("-", ""));
            }


            if (marketFeedBean.isChangeGain.equals(ChangeStatus.HIGH)) {


                holder.indexChange.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.orange));
            } else if (marketFeedBean.isChangeGain.equals(ChangeStatus.LOW)) {

                holder.indexChange.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.orange));
            } else {
                holder.indexChange.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.black));
            }

        }

            else {

                try
                {
                    String sm = rows.get(position);
                    holder.indexName.setText(sm.split(":", -1)[1]);
                    holder.scripName.setText(sm.split(":", -1)[0]);
                    holder.sector.setText(scripBean != null ? scripBean.getSectorName() : null);
                    holder.nameIcon.setText(sm.split(":", -1)[0].substring(0, 1));
                    holder.SymbolName.setText(scripBean != null ? scripBean.getScripName() : null);
                    holder.indexValue.setText(R.string.zero_amount);
                    holder.indexChange.setText(R.string.zero_percent);
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Utilities.handleException(e);
                }


            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Utilities.handleException(e);
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Logs.market = null;
                Logs.scrip = null;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SymbolDetailsActivity.class);
                String market = holder.indexName.getText().toString();
                String Scrip = holder.scripName.getText().toString();
                Logs.market = market;
                Logs.scrip = Scrip;
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }


    public void updateGraph() {

        ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();



        try{


            if(marketWatchGraphBeans != null)
            {
                for(int index=0; index<marketWatchGraphBeans.size(); index++)
                    {
                        list.add(marketWatchGraphBeans.get(index).OpenPrice);
                        list.add(marketWatchGraphBeans.get(index).Average);
                        list.add(marketWatchGraphBeans.get(index).High);
                        list.add(marketWatchGraphBeans.get(index).Low);
                        list.add(marketWatchGraphBeans.get(index).closePrice);
                        list.add(marketWatchGraphBeans.get(index).lastTrdPrice);
                    }
            }

            if (list.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    String listValue = String.valueOf(list.get(i));
                    if(!listValue.equals("null")) {
                        yVals1.add(new Entry(i, Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(list.get(i)))));
                    }
                }


                mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(true);
                YAxis leftAxis = mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisLeft();
                leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);

                set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals1, "Price");
                set1.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.gray_light));
                LineDataSet set2 = new LineDataSet(yVals1, "Price");
                set2.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green));
                set2.setDrawCircles(false);
                set2.setDrawValues(false);
                set1.setDrawCircles(false);

                LineData data = new LineData(set1);
                set1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
                set2.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);


                mViewHolder.symbolChart.setData(data);

                set2.setDrawFilled(true);
                set2.setFillDrawable(drawablePositive);
                set2.setFillFormatter((dataSet, dataProvider) -> mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisLeft().getAxisMinimum());


                set1.setDrawFilled(true);
                set1.setFillDrawable(drawablePositive);
                set1.setFillFormatter((dataSet, dataProvider) -> mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisLeft().getAxisMinimum());


                set1.setLineWidth(1);
                set2.setLineWidth(1);
                set1.setDrawValues(false);
                set2.setDrawValues(false);



                mViewHolder.symbolChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
                mViewHolder.symbolChart.invalidate();


            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Utilities.handleException(e);
        }

    }

    private void drawLineChart(ViewHolder mChartViewHolder) {
        setData(mChartViewHolder);
    }

    private void setData(ViewHolder mChartViewHolder) {

        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();


            values.add(new Entry(1,10f));
            values.add(new Entry(2,12f));
            values.add(new Entry(3,8f));
            values.add(new Entry(4,12f));
            values.add(new Entry(5,3f));
            values.add(new Entry(6,2f));
            values.add(new Entry(7,9f));
            values.add(new Entry(8,5f));
            values.add(new Entry(9,11f));




        if (mChartViewHolder.symbolChart.getData() != null &&
                mChartViewHolder.symbolChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
            set1 = (LineDataSet) mChartViewHolder.symbolChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            set1.setValues(values);

            set1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChartViewHolder.symbolChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            mChartViewHolder.symbolChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            // create a dataset and give it a type
            set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "DataSet 1");

            set1.setDrawIcons(false);
            set1.setDrawCircles(false);
            set1.setLineWidth(1f);
            set1.setCircleRadius(3f);

            // draw points as solid circles
            set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
            set1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            set1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
            set1.setDrawFilled(true);
            set1.setFillDrawable(drawablePositive);


            // customize legend entry
            set1.setFormLineWidth(1f);
//            set1.setFormLineDashEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10f, 5f}, 0f));
            set1.setFormSize(12.f);

            // text size of values
            set1.setValueTextSize(9f);

            // draw selection line as dashed
//            set1.enableDashedHighlightLine(10f, 5f, 0f);

            // set the filled area
            set1.setDrawFilled(true);
            set1.setFillFormatter(new IFillFormatter() {
                @Override
                public float getFillLinePosition(ILineDataSet dataSet, LineDataProvider dataProvider) {
                    return mChartViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisLeft().getAxisMinimum();
                }
            });

            // set color of filled area
            if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
                // drawables only supported on api level 18 and above
//                Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mChartViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), R.drawable.remove);
//                set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
            } else {
                set1.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
            }



            ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            dataSets.add(set1); // add the data sets

            // create a data object with the data sets
            LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);

            // set data
            mChartViewHolder.symbolChart.setData(data);
        }
    }

    private void customiseChart(ViewHolder mViewHolder) {
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setDragEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setScaleYEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setScaleXEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
//        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getLineData().setDrawValues(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisRight().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisRight().setZeroLineColor(Color.BLACK);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.getAxisRight().setAxisLineColor(Color.BLACK);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setMaxHighlightDistance(150);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setPinchZoom(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.setAnimationCacheEnabled(false);
        mViewHolder.symbolChart.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    public synchronized void refill(ArrayList<String> data) {
        this.rows.clear();
        this.rows.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }



    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView indexName;
        public TextView SymbolName;
        public TextView indexValue;
        public TextView scripName;
        public TextView nameIcon;
        public LineChart symbolChart;
        public ImageButton imageButton;
        private AutoResizeTextView indexChange;
        public ArrayList<Entry> values;
        private TextView sector;
        public CardView cardView;
        public Context context;
        public String Scrip;
        public String market;
        public LineData data;

        
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            context = itemView.getContext();
            indexName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.symbolMarket);
            scripName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainSymbolName);
            SymbolName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.symbolName);
            nameIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_icon);
            indexValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.indexValue);
            indexChange = itemView.findViewById(R.id.indexChange);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crdlayout);
            sector = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSector);
            symbolChart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.marketwatchgraph);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Some constructive feedback-  you really need to break that massive bind function into subfunctions.  As it is now, your eyes just glaze over trying to read it.  A good rule of thumb is if a function is much bigger than 1 screen, you need to break it up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use notifyDataSetChanged().  That tells the recycler view the entire data set has changed, and it wipes out state on everything because it thinks everything is reset.  Instead use notifyItemChanged, notifyItemInserted, etc to tell it to only change the ones that have new data.  You can user DiffUtil to help you by comparing two lists and sending change commands for you.

If your architecture is such you can't tell which ones changed, that's part of the problem that needs to be addressed.

Comment: how to pass position parameter in notify method? can you help further please?